# Using three monitors with a GTX 460

Tags: multiple-monitors

I recently purchased a GTX-460 and expected it to be able to supply 3 monitors. However, this does not seem to be the case (that's what you get for trusting a random store clerk instead of doing your own research I guess). However, I have also purchased the screens already, so just settling for dual head is no option either. Thus, what's the cheapest way for getting my three heads to work? My PSU delivers 530 watts and an SLI capable mainboard is at hand.

Comment: Finally, I decided to buy a cheap Club 3D GT 430, plugged that thing into the second PCI-E on my mainboard. Works perfect for Windows 7, Ubuntu not working yet, but seems merely a configuration issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want a different view on each screen? If so, you'll need a second video card or a new video card that supports 3 monitors (ATI Eyefinity line for example).

If you want 3 monitors but you want 2 different views (1 + 2 cloned), you can always get a DVI splitter (make sure that your card has Dual Link DVI ports) and split one of the signals. Or another type of splitter based on the connections that you are using.

[image]

Comment: I want a different View (i.e. extended desktop) on my screens, so appearently I need a second video card. Are there any requirements for that card (e.g. same manufacturer or driver...) or can I buy some cheap, passive cooled PCI card?

Comment: Well, my answer has both scenarios covered. Sorry about the bad news. Nvidia cards do not support 3 different monitors to be hooked up. You can always buy a second card to handle the task, though, assuming your system can handle it.

Comment: @th3dude - There are plenty of nVidia cards that support 3 or even 4 outputs, but they're pretty much all Quadro workstation cards.

Comment: Maybe you missed my edit. I do unterstand that I can buy a second card. But are there any requirements on that card? Like same Manufacturer or Driver? Or some Connection (PCI vs PCI-E)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter. They recommend the same card, but since yours is so high end, a cheap card should do the trick. I'd stick with nVidia, though. You may want to look into this more before buying, but it should work. As for connection type, that's a really good question that I don't know the answer to.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your information. Do you mind if I leave this open until someone can provide any information on connection type and especially manufacturer? (my local hardware supplyer has a nice and cheap ATI (PCI-E) on sale...)

Comment: @Matthias - The answers to your question, unfortunately, vary card to card.  The best thing to do is to find a card that at least uses the same driver - mixing drivers may or may not work.  You should avoid mixing manufacturers (although it MAY work).

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a card that uses the same driver (i.e. two identical video cards).  I use a Nvidia 3700 Quadro and a NVS 295 Quadro - same exact driver.  This was a requirement in Vista and I think it is the same in Windows 7.  XP might have let you use different drivers - not sure.  It is best to use the same driver though.